# Adding runtime label as content in checkbox wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am dynamically creating the checkboxes at runtime and also applying the style at runtime. Designer has developed a checkbox like control that am applying at runtime. and he put a Label on that checkbox control to show the Text on the checkbox control as its content from the Database. But when i applying content of checkbox or label at runtime, it displays at the back of that checkbox control that is developed by the designer. How to make use of the Label control to show the content from the database on the checkbox control.

Kindly Suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your ControlTemplate.  My guess is that you are putting the label in a layer behind the checkmark, but that's it - just a guess.  If you post your ControlTemplate, you'll likely get an answer fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like your designer forgot to include a `<ContentPresenter/>` in his checkbox template.  If there is no `ContentPresenter`, the text you add as a comment will never be shown.

Here is an example of a custom CheckBox ControlTemplate that includes the required ContentPresenter:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
  <DockPanel>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
      <Path x:Name="check" Width="10" Height="10"
            Data=".... data for checkmark in checkbox ..." />
    </Border>
    <ContentPresenter/>
  </DockPanel>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger ... trigger for changing checkmark ... />
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to review your checkbox style. It is supposed to be that label(textbox) in style liyng under checkbox mark. Here is nearly right code for the chekcbox template:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Border Grid.Column="0">
      <!--Place your mark here-->
   </Border>
   <Border Grid.Column="1">
      <!--Place your label here-->
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: But am applying his style at runtime. You can check or uncheck that jus like a normal checkbox. I want to display the Text on that as Label Content. If I remove the style, the normal checkbox is coming along with its content.

like: checkbox   BreakFast

I need a breakfast on top of that checkbox as Label's content.

Comment: It's no matter when you apply style, control template is wrong. The checkmark has to be on the left side, label content has to be put on other free space. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(VS.85).aspx By this link provided CheckBox style and corresponding control template. Check the layout of you controltemplate and given in that example. It helps you to find out, why your checkbox has such strange behaviour.